# What is the reason for dropping reference dummy variable before performing logistic regression?

Tags: statistics, logistic-regression, categorical-data, dummy-variable

I am trying to use logistic regression to do binary classification. Before doing logistic regression, I'm using dummy variables for categorical variables. For example, age has three categories (16-64, 65-74, 75 above) and if I use dummy variables, I get age_1, age_2, and age_3. If I remember correctly, I am supposed to drop age_1 (reference group) but I can't recall the reason why I have to do this. I tried to google it but I guess I'm not using the right keyword to search for it. Could you guys explain the reason why dropping reference group is necessary?

Comment: This is not really a coding question, and would probably be a better fit for Cross Validated. To answer your question: You need to make sure that your design matrix `X` has full rank. You can understand this in the context of OLS models, where the OLS estimators are dependent on the inverse of the Gramian matrix `X^t X`, which only exists if `X` has full rank.

Comment: [continued] There are *a lot* of posts on Cross Validated and on the net that provide details; keywords would be "dummy variable encoding", "dummy variable trap", see e.g. [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24389/omitted-dummy-variable-coefficient-in-ols), [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_variable_(statistics)#Incorporating_a_dummy_independent).